# How to make a list of arrays, not their symbols, in Lisp?

Tags: lambda, common-lisp, apply, sbcl

I'm trying to make a function to get a delta between arrays, but right now just want to make a subset: get Nth element.

```
 (defvar p1 #(1 2))
 (defvar p2 #(3 4))
 (mapcar '(lambda (x) (aref x 0)) '(p1 p2))

 debugger invoked on a TYPE-ERROR in ...
   The value P1 is not of type ARRAY.
```

The same error if I make it with make-array.

How do I apply the lambda function, or how to apply `(aref x 0)`, or `(aref x N)` in general case?

In the end I want to make a function that returns a delta: p2 - p1.

Comment: the title of this question is wrong. The problem is not about getting elements in arrays, but about creating a list of arrays instead of a list symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAPCAR takes a function as first argument.  `'(lambda (x) (aref x 0))` is the same as `(quote (lambda (x) (aref x 0)))`, and this is *not* a function.  You want to make it a function with `(function (lambda (x) (aref x 0)))`, which can be written shorter as `#'(lambda (x) (aref x 0))`, or even (because of a standard macro) `(lambda (x) (aref x 0))`.

`'(p1 p2)` is the same as `(quote (p1 p2))`.  QUOTE means that the arguments are *not evaluated*, so the names "P1" and "P2" stand for themselves, not for their values.  The type error you get is that the symbol `'P1` is not an array, it just has an array as value.  In order to get a list of the values, use LIST: `(list p1 p2)`.

In conclusion: `(mapcar #'(lambda (x) (aref x 0)) (list p1 p2))`

EDIT:  For subtracting vectors, you should look into the [MAP](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_map.htm) function; note that you can provide multiple sequences.

Comment: This answers the superficial problem without addressing the ultimate goal of getting the delta.

Comment: xach, I gave a hint in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

To get a delta vector containing the difference between two vectors, try this:

```
(map 'vector #'- p2 p1)
```

In your example, it returns:

```
#(2 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you have quoted the list, i.e.

```
'(p1 p2)
```

You should instead have

```
(list p1 p2)
```

because in your program you actually try to apply mapcar to a list containing two elements, the symbol p1 and the symbol p2.

Answer (score 0):

antti.huima has it right. However, there is another error in your code:

```
(mapcar #'(lambda (x) (aref x 0)) (list p1 p2))
```

Note the hash mark before the single quote that precedes the `lambda`.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to, you can use SYMBOL-VALUE:

```
(defvar p1 #(1 2))
(defvar p2 #(3 4))
(mapcar #'(lambda (x) (aref (symbol-value x) 0)) '(p1 p2))
```